# Difference between 别 and 不

Tags: word-choice, negation

I know that a typical way to negate a verb is to stick 不 in front of it. But I learned some phrases that use 别 instead: 别担心, 别客气 and so on, all of them in short polite fixed phrases. I know that I could change 别 into 不 in those phrases too.

So what's the difference between those words?

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you started. – Tom Au Feb 4 at 20:18

Answer (score 10, accepted):

不 means "not" and 别 means "do not." One is a simple negation, and the other is a (negative) command.

Comment: To add more background to this answer, it might help if you know that 别 is actually a contraction of 不要.  (Note that this usage is separate from the original usage of 别 meaning "other".)

Comment: Don't forget, @Claw, you can also add your own answer if you have extra information.

Comment: @DonKirkby: Yep, I'm aware; I just felt that my supplement didn't add significantly more information to merit it's own response and that Tom's response sufficiently answered the question anyway.

Comment: @Claw Where did you learn that? I'm curious.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete: I don't exactly remember where I learned it, but I've seen it variously mentioned by teachers and on the Internet.  Interestingly, in trying to find a more authoritative source, I came upon a paper (http://dspace.xmu.edu.cn/dspace/bitstream/2288/1220/1/%E7%A6%81%E6%AD%A2%E5%89%AF%E8%AF%8D_%E5%88%AB_%E6%9D%A5%E6%BA%90%E5%86%8D%E8%80%83.pdf) that acknowledges the common belief that 别 is a contraction 不要, but instead argues that it is actually a contraction of 不必.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in simple words: 不 means "not" while 别 means "don't do something", it is also good to compare them with another negation word:没有， which literally means lack of the action:having, so in other words it means don't have or doesn't have. Don't forget in Chinese we don't conjugate the verbs.